# Can i remove inline styles with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove **inline style** from a **span** or **div** or **...**

```
<span style="font-size: 8pt;">some texts</span>
```

Can i remove **font-size** from **span** with jQuery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the entire `style` attribute then you can use `removeAttr('style');`

```js
$('span').removeAttr('style');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size: 8pt; color: #c00;">some texts</span>
```

If you want to override the setting back to default whilst retaining other inline styles, use `css('font-size', 'inherit');`

```js
$('span').css('font-size', 'inherit');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size: 8pt; color: #c00;">some texts</span>
```

Comment: Yep, stated that in the answer: `If you want to remove the entire style attribute...`

Comment: Better to use css in a separate file, then remove and add classes or ids to manipulate your content with javacript/jquery.  Do you have access to the html?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely removed the inline styles in any of your html elements.

You can you the `removeAttr` method provided by jQuery.

```
$('span, div').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove inline style**

```js
$('span').removeAttr('style');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size: 8px; color: red">some texts</span>
```

**Update multiple property in css**

```js
$('span').css({
  'font-size' : '20px',
  color: 'blue'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size: 8pt;">some texts</span>
```

**Update single property using css**

```js
$('span').css('font-size', '20px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size: 8pt;">some texts</span>
```